# Unable to identify the REST API URL request for create-user-pool-client in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-cognito

I wish to know how to create a user-pool-client in cognito-idp using a REST API URL.

I couldn't figure it out in the [API reference documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPoolClient.html).

The similar AWS CLI command that I referred to was [`create-user-pool-client`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/create-user-pool-client.html).

Comment: I don't think there is a rest API for that. The is the documentation for the create-user-pool-client https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_CreateUserPoolClient.html, it only mentions SDK's available per language.

Comment: @HenriqueDroog..thank you so much